# How to do numeric validation using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation

How to do numeric validation using JQuery. I have to validate my price field using JQuery. any body knows please share your knowledge with me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also good for form validation:

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Theres an example:

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

Answer (score 5):

If your looking for form validation, you can look into the validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

However if you just want some sample code, it could be as simple as this:

```
$(function() {
  $('ref-to-input').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val().match(/[^\d]/)) {
      // invalid chars detected
    }
  });
});
```

you could also filter your input to only allow numeric characters:

```
$(function() {
  $('ref-to-input').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]/, ''));
  });
});
```

Edit: don't forget to always use server side checking

Comment: +1 for `don't forget to always use server side checking`... because client side is checking always easy to bypass.. :)

Comment: @Reigel +1 for client side checking being easy to bypass. It is absolutely trivial so ALWAYS check on the server side also.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery validation plugin

http://www.bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

It contains all the validations like, require, format, size, range, value

Answer (score 1):

```
function IsNumeric(sText){
    var ValidChars = "0123456789.";
    var IsNumber = true;
    var Char;
    for (i = 0; i < sText.length && IsNumber == true; i++) {
        Char = sText.charAt(i);
        if (ValidChars.indexOf(Char) == -1) {
            IsNumber = false;
        }
    }
    return IsNumber;
}
```

USE:

```
if ( IsNumeric(my_number) )
//do some here...
```

Comment: Isn't it just a lot easier (and shorter) to use regular expressions?

Comment: Well, not quite... That regex wouldn't catch e.g. '3.1' or '3.145'. But anyways, your answer is just an ugly way to go around using a simple regex to check for numeric input.

Comment: yes, you are right for the regex it should be like this `/\d[\d.,]*/` but i'm still of my opinion that depend on what the OP is going to do since there are a lot of price format, you need to take care of many circumstance!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to apply this method in Jquery and you can validate your textbox to just accept number only.

```
function IsNumberKeyWithoutDecimal(element) {    
var value = $(element).val();
var regExp = "^\\d+$";
return value.match(regExp); 
}
```

Please see working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ImIruPEf/1/edit)